# Using termios() to replace EOF?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I have a psuedo terminal running on linux C, opened as shown:

```
else
{ 
     struct termios slave_orig_term_settings; // Saved terminal settings
     struct termios new_term_settings; // Current terminal settings

    // CHILD
    close(fdm);

    rc = tcgetattr(fds, &slave_orig_term_settings);

    new_term_settings = slave_orig_term_settings;

    new_term_settings.c_cc[VEOF] = '|';
    new_term_settings.c_oflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ECHOK | ECHONL | ISIG | ICRNL);

    cfmakeraw (&new_term_settings);

    tcsetattr (fds, TCSANOW, &new_term_settings);

}
```

When reading from the pipe, I can make a non blocking read() which will return after, for example, 5 seconds. The problem is that if I execute a command like "ls", which returns in several ms, it will wait the full 5 seconds before returning.

I understand using a physical GUI terminal, and not a psuedo terminal like this, the user can press CTRL^D and have EOF sent at the end of each output.

I want this effect, so my program can say "OK, I have received this certain byte, which means the terminal is done outputting, and I can now return this output back to the caller, and I know there is no more output to read".

I understand this is done with termios() function (or it's wrapper stty), but I can't get it working. I want the terminal to send me the '|' char instead of ctrl^d (\x04) upon completion of output, but it isn't working.

For clarity, upon completion of output (via read()), I want to receive the '|' byte. So if I send 'pwd' command, I get this output:

```
 $ pwd
 /home/user/dir
 $|
```

Could someone please tell me how to edit this code to acheive that effect?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT - select() code

```
while ( (bytes = select(pipe + 1, &fd_in, NULL, NULL, &tv)) )
{       
            if (FD_ISSET(pipe, &fd_in))
            {

                read (pipe...)
```

The behaviour of the above code is as I've described, to wait for the full value of tv, even if there is nothing on the pipe, before returning.

Comment: The `.c_cc[VEOF]` special character is only used in "canonical" mode (`ICANON` bit set in `.c_lflags`), but `cfmakeraw` sets "raw" mode (`ICANON` bit not set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `c_cc[VEOF]` will never be sent to you. For example, the default value of `c_cc[VEOF]` is `CTRL-D` but you'll not see the `CTRL-D` on the end of file when the user presses `CTRL-D`. Instead you are notified (e.g. by `read()` returning `0`) that you're reaching the end of the file.

Usually when the child is done with its work it'll explicitly `close()` the pty slave side so the pty master side will get `EOF`.

Regarding

> I can make a non blocking read() which will return after, for example, 5 seconds. The problem is that if I execute a command like "ls", which returns in several ms, **it will wait the full 5 seconds before returning**.

Not sure how you write the code but you can use `select()` or `poll()` which can notify you immediately when there's data available for reading.

---

According to `select()`'s man page:

> `select()`  and  `pselect()` allow a program to monitor multiple file descriptors, waiting **until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready"** for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible).  A file descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform a corresponding I/O operation  (e.g.,  `read(2)`  without blocking, or a sufficiently small `write(2)`).

Comment: This is what I feared. I'm using a non blocking read() via select(). Is there any way to make read() return 0 without waiting for the value defined in timeval passed to select() on the read() file descriptor? I want to avoid waiting for the full value of timeval passed to select if the program returns before that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can set `.c_cc[VTIME]` to set a timeout in deciseconds in "raw" (non-canonical) mode.

Comment: I see on another question that VTIME has no effect on non blocking sockets.

Comment: With regard to your edit on select()/poll(), the problem is that if select() doesn't find data available for reading, it will wait for timeval, if I'm using it wrong, can you show me the proper way to make it return if input has finished?

Comment: You can find many `select()` examples online. Paste your code so people can help see why it's not working for you. Ask a new question if necessary.

Comment: I've editted the question to include the select() code.

Comment: Having researched select() a lot, getting it to behave the way you described I believe is not possible, it's always going to wait for the timeout time struct value before returning, if not please show the code proving what you say.

Comment: What you say is technically correct "can notify you immediately when there's data available for reading", it will not notify you when there is no longer data available. I'd recommend you edit your answer as not to confuse people.

Comment: Updated my answer and added excerpts from `select()`'s man page. Since your pasted code is not complete I'm not sure what's wrong. Did you call `FD_ZERO(&fd_in)` and `FD_SET(pipe, &fd_in)` before `select()`?

Comment: You'll never know if there's new data coming until you see the `EOF`, before reaching `EOF` you have to repeat the `select-read` loop. As I said the child explicitly `close()` the pty slave side so the master would get `EOF`.

Comment: Yes, I did. What I posted is the only relevant part. select() will tell you if there's data to read from the file descriptor. Once that data is read(), select()/poll()/etc have no way of knowing if there is any more data to read. The behaviour I wanted is not possible (of course, if you can show code proving otherwise I'd be happy to see), I have to parse the output looking for some indicator that there's nothing more to receive. Thus why any networking protocol, MIME, etc has this "end of transfer" terminator built in. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: select()/poll()/etc isn't going to tell me if the terminal is finished writing to stdout... it has no way to know this...